# Split up the [split] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[split](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/split) is all over - it's about splitting files, DVDs, splitting windows/screen into two, Excel formula to split contents - I propose that we kill [split](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/split)

Comment: And how you will tag questions related to file-splitting, screen splitting and DVD splitting? Add new tag for each of them? Like `split-file`, `split-DVD`, `split-screen`... Or maybe just leave them with split tag?)

Comment: @Jet I created a post to add objects to transitive verbs... 
http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8292/reduce-tag-ambiguity-by-requiring-objects-for-transitive-verbs

Comment: Good decision, now it's OK, splits will not be alone

Comment: Does status-planned include decisions on what to do with the existing tags (convert selected ones or all to specific tags as @Jet suggests)?  Are all of these needed?

Comment: @fixer1234 Not needed, just kill it

Comment: Follow-up: [Split off split](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11279/87805). It's done now.

Answer (score 2):

I torched it from the last nine normal questions and flagged a locked one. That flag just went through, deleting the post, leaving **zero** questions tagged.

RIP [split](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/split).

Answer (score -1):

I partially agree. However, I can imagine how some users are better at "splitting" than others (no matter the concrete case). I would argue that even though it's so generic, it could still easily be added to my favorite tags, since I have quite a lot of script experience in scraping and splitting all kinds of data. But then again, splitting DVDs doesn't really exactly fall under that category.

Comment: I think you are looking for text-editing.