# Reduce Tag Ambiguity by Requiring Objects for Transitive Verbs

Tags: discussion, tags

It's all in the title I'd say...

In short, I'm suggesting that we add 'object' validation for single-transitive verb tags  without object qualifiers... For instance ... 'split' would require the object to reduce ambiguity.

**I.E.**

split would become :: 'split-screen, split-file...'
limit would become :: 'page-limit, memory-limit...'

Comment: An interesting way of describing the problem but honestly works pretty well

Comment: What about `split` - the software of that name?

Comment: @0xC0000022L Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @EddieB: `split` in the GNU coreutils. I'm sure there are more incarnations than this one.

Comment: @0xC0000022L :: Gotchya... I'd say the same applies `gnu-split`

Comment: @EddieB: Fair enough :)

Comment: Will gnu-split show up if you just start typing split? If not, I'd go with split-gnu.

Comment: @trlkly yeah... questions about how to split the GNU community, I'm not sure that's on topic, through.

Comment: @Braiam I'm not talking about interpretation of meaning, but autocomplete. Isn't the whole idea that people will just type "split" and then they will see the other options with nouns and realize they have to pick one of those? All I'm asking is whether "gnu-split" would show up if you started typing "split". Or, to use examples in the OP, would typing "limit" make "page-limit" and "memory-limit" show up? If so, I'm all for this. If not, I think we'd need to either make all disambigs start with the original word, or get the software changed. (I don't ask questions a lot, so I don't know.)

Comment: @Braiam Not that I didn't think the joke was funny.

Comment: @trlkly if you type "split" it will show all tags that contain somewhere the word "split". Yes, and yes.