# Should we recalibrate the [calibration] tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

The [calibration](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/calibration) tag is another broad tag that includes questions about calibrating displays, mice, batteries, printers, etc.

I think it is helpful to have tags specifically about calibration issues, though. I suggest, along the lines of [this meta post](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8292/76571), that this tag be split up according to what is being calibrated.

New tags would be:

[display-calibration](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/display-calibration)
[mouse-calibration](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mouse-calibration)
[printer-calibration](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/printer-calibration)

Most of the questions in [calibration](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/calibration) will go to [display-calibration](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/display-calibration) so the other calibration tags may be unnecessary.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure if these tags are really necessary, but I like this as a first step.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg or we could just burn the damn thing.

Comment: I feel it'd be enough to tag with the device/monitor/whatever needs calibrating without needing a separate tag - My vote would be burn :)