# Split off [split]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-cleanup-request

The tag [split](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/split) is used for lots of things and not used consistently for anything.

It has been planned to make it go [since 2014](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8260/split-up-the-split-tag). Can we burn it now?

Comment: "Not needed, just kill it  – Sathya♦ Jan 25 '15 at 7:18"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's done. There are now zero questions tagged [split](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/split).

<sup>The original content of this post follows.</sup>

---

The meta question you linked has the [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) moderator tag, so we have the official go-ahead to make it vanish. You can help remove it from posts that have other issues (spelling, grammar); such edits will be approved if you improve the post significantly and mention the tag destruction in the edit comment.

Users with the edit privilege (>2K reputation) can and should clean up the rest.